# Изменять цвет лейблу по мере пингования

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite3, ping, qlabel

В общем, в *Б*Д у меня есть все координаты расположения лейблов, нужно чтобы их цвет менялся по ходу продвижения пинга и каждый `id` ip-адреса отвечал соответствующему `id` лейбла.

Еесли например у **1** ip-адреса цвет зелёный, то и у соответствующего лейбла он должен быть зелёным, у меня сейчас они загораются все сразу

Нужно как-то их связать, по идее в бд есть `id` этих координат

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 3

import sys
import os
import sqlite3
import subprocess
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(818, 469)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/ico/Python.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:#b2b2b2;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 691, 383))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Снимок.PNG);")
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setToolTip("")
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 5, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #FFAA00;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(75, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(291, 0))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 16777215))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 1, 4, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(54, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(153, 243, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 4, 2, 1, 2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem4, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(69, 31))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem5, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 297, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem6, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 818, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Лог панель"))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Изменение ip и данных"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Настройка ip"))
        self.pushButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Пинг старт/стоп"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Yi"))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Отчистить поле лог панели"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить таблицу"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Updae"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг ip"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip аддреса"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Порты"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
import res_rc


#----------------------------------------------- 1 пинг
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str, tuple)

    def __init__(self, dictIP):
        super().__init__()
        self.dictIP = dictIP

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for k, v in self.dictIP.items():
                if v[2] == 0:
                    response = subprocess.run(["ping", k, "-n", "1", "-w", "100"], shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                    response = response.returncode
                    self.msleep(1)
                    self.threadSignal.emit(response, k, v)

#----------------------------------------------- 2 пинг
class WorkThread_1(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal_1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str, tuple)

    def __init__(self, k, v):
        super().__init__()
        self.k_1 = k
        self.v_1 = v

    def run(self):
        response_1 = subprocess.run(["ping", self.k_1, "-n", "4", "-w", "100"], shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        response_1 = response_1.returncode
        self.msleep(1)
        self.threadSignal_1.emit(response_1, self.k_1, self.v_1)
#------------------------------------------------

class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
    
    def __init__(
        self, 
        background=QColor("white"),
        parent=None
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._background = background
        self._change_stylesheet()

    @property
    def background(self):
        return self._background

    @background.setter
    def background(self, color):
        if self._background == color:
            return
        self._background = color
        self._change_stylesheet()

    def _change_stylesheet(self):
        qss = "QLabel {background-color:%s}" % (
            self.background.name(),
        )
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit(self.objectName(), self.text())

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startThread)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clear_plainText)

        self.thread = None

        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.table_index = 0
        self.row_count = 1
        self.count = 0

        self.tab_1()

        self.thread_1_list = []
        self.thread_1_num = 0

    # Отвечает за лейблы
    def coordinate(self, response, response_1): # response, response_1 - результат пинга, прошел или нет
        # Подключение к БД
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT x, y, w, h FROM coords"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        # x, y - место | w, h - размер
        for x, y, w, h in records:
            lab = Label(parent=self.ui.tab)
            lab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x, y, w, h))
            lab.setObjectName("")
            lab.setText("")
            lab.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel)
            if response == 1:
                if response_1:
                    lab.background = QColor("#fa7f72")
                else:
                    lab.background = QColor("#ffaa00")
            else:
                lab.background = QColor("#54e346")

    def onClickLabel(self, objName, text):
        print(f'Вы кликнули: objName={objName}, text={text}')

    # Заполнение таблицы пинга
    def tab_1(self):
        # Подключение к БД
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip, Yi FROM ips"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        # Перебор ip адресов
        for row, value in enumerate(records):
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value[0]))
            item_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value[1]))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, item)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item_2)
            self.row_count += 1

    # Отчиска плейн текст
    def clear_plainText(self):
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.clear()
       
    # Старт\стоп пинга
    def startThread(self):
        dictIP = {}
        for row in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
            item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 1)
            if not item.checkState():
                item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("white"))
                item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("white"))
            dictIP[item.text()] = (row, 0, item.checkState())

        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = WorkThread(dictIP)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.coordinate)
            self.thread.start()
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Stop thread")

            style_stop = """QPushButton {
                         background-color: #fa7f72;
                         }
                         QPushButton:hover {
                         background-color: white;
                         }
                         QPushButton:pressed {
                         color: #626AB0;
                         background-color: #D5D4D4;
                         }"""

            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet(style_stop)
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.thread = None
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Start thread")

            style_start = """QPushButton {
                         background-color: #54e346;
                         }
                         QPushButton:hover {
                         background-color: white;
                         }
                         QPushButton:pressed {
                         color: #626AB0;
                         background-color: #D5D4D4;
                         }"""

            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet(style_start)

    # Отвечает за 1 пинг
    def on_threadSignal(self, response, k, v):
        #print(response, k, v)
        item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v[0], v[1])
        item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v[0], v[1]+1)
        #item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if response == 1:
            thread_1 = WorkThread_1(k, v)
            self.thread_1_list.append(thread_1)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].threadSignal_1.connect(self.on_threadSignal_1)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].threadSignal_1.connect(self.coordinate)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].start()
            self.thread_1_num += 1
        else:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#54e346"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#54e346"))

    # Отвечает за 2 пинг
    def on_threadSignal_1(self, response_1, k_1, v_1):
        #print(response_1, k_1, v_1)
        item_1 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v_1[0], v_1[1])
        item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v_1[0], v_1[1]+1)
        #item_1.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if response_1:
            item_1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#fa7f72"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#fa7f72"))

            sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip = '{}'""".format(k_1)
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in records:
                self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(f'{row[4]} | {row[1]} | {row[2]}\n{row[3]}\n')
            
        else:
            item_1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#ffaa00"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#ffaa00"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

БД

```
import sqlite3

try:
    # Создание таблиц
    connect = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    print("База данных подключена к SQLite")
    
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ips(
                      id INTEGER,
                      ip INTEGER,
                      Gor TEXT,
                      Yi TEXT,
                      Location TEXT);""")

    connect.commit()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coords(
                      id INTEGER,
                      x INTEGER,
                      y INTEGER,
                      w INTEGER,
                      h INTEGER);""")

    connect.commit()

    # Добавление данных в таблицы

    records = [[f"{i}", f"192.168.{i}.9", "None", "None", "None"] for i in range(1, 101)]
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ips VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", records)

    coord = [("1", "395",  "148", "10",  "10"), ("2", "435",  "110", "10",  "10"), ("3", "450",  "140", "10",  "10")]
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO coords VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", coord)
    connect.commit()

    print("Запись успешно добавлена")
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", error)

finally:
    if connect:
        connect.close()
        print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

Comment: Как мне каждому создаваемому лейблу присвоить уникальный id ?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Куда мне цикл вытаскивания координат вставить ?

Я добавил словарь `self.dictMove = {}` и в методе `tab_1()` формирую его:

```
    sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip, Yi, x, y FROM ips"""      # <----
    ...
    self.dictMove = { ip: (x, y) for ip, yi, x, y in records}     # <----
```

и в методе `coordinate()` рисуем лабелы так:

```
    lab.move(* self.dictMove[iP])                     # <----  !!!
```

обратите внимание на **`*`**

```
import sys
import os
import random                                                       # 
import sqlite3
import subprocess
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(818, 469)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/ico/Python.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:#b2b2b2;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 691, 383))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(im.png);")            # ! im.png
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setToolTip("")
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 5, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #FFAA00;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(75, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(291, 0))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 16777215))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 1, 4, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(54, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(153, 243, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 4, 2, 1, 2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem4, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(69, 31))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem5, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 297, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem6, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 818, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Лог панель"))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Изменение ip и данных"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Настройка ip"))
        self.pushButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Пинг старт/стоп"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Yi"))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Отчистить поле лог панели"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить таблицу"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Updae"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг ip"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip аддреса"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Порты"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
#import res_rc


#------------------------ 1 пинг
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str, tuple)

    def __init__(self, dictIP):
        super().__init__()
        self.dictIP = dictIP
        # print(f'dictIP = {self.dictIP}')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for k, v in self.dictIP.items():
                if v[2] == 0:
                    response = subprocess.run(
                        ["ping", k, "-n", "1", "-w", "100"], 
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                    )
                    response = response.returncode
                    self.msleep(1)
                    self.threadSignal.emit(response, k, v)

#-------------------------- 2 пинг
class WorkThread_1(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal_1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str, tuple)

    def __init__(self, k, v):
        super().__init__()
        self.k_1 = k
        self.v_1 = v

    def run(self):
        response_1 = subprocess.run(
            ["ping", self.k_1, "-n", "4", "-w", "100"], 
            shell=True, 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        response_1 = response_1.returncode
        self.msleep(1)
        self.threadSignal_1.emit(response_1, self.k_1, self.v_1)


class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
    
    def __init__(
        self, 
        background=QColor("white"),
        parent=None
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._background = background
        self._change_stylesheet()
        
        self.setFixedSize(10, 10)                                    # 

    @property
    def background(self):
        return self._background

    @background.setter
    def background(self, color):
        if self._background == color:
            return
        self._background = color
        self._change_stylesheet()

    def _change_stylesheet(self):
        qss = "QLabel {background-color:%s}" % (
            self.background.name(),
        )
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit(str(self.pos()), self.background.name())        # 


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startThread)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clear_plainText)

        self.thread = None

        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.table_index = 0
        self.row_count = 1
        self.count = 0

        self.dictMove = {}                                           # <----
        self.tab_1()

        self.thread_1_list = []
        self.thread_1_num = 0

        self.dictLbls = {}                                           #

# coordinate
    # Отвечает за лейблы
    # response - результат пинга, прошел или нет
    # iP - iP  
#    def coordinate(self, response, response_1): 
    def coordinate(self, response, iP):                             #

# +++ * vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        _lbl = self.dictLbls.get(iP)                                # 
        if not _lbl:                                                # 
            # вам надо где-то в БД соответствующему iP имет pos для label !!!
            # для тестирования формирую рандомно
#            x = random.randint(20, 650)                             # <---- убрал
#            y = random.randint(20, 350)                             # <---- убрал

            lab = Label(parent=self.ui.tab)
#            lab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x+random.randint(10, 200), y+random.randint(10, 200), w, h))
            lab.setObjectName("")
            lab.setText("")
            lab.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel)
            
#            lab.move(x, y)                                          # <---- убрал 
            lab.move(* self.dictMove[iP])                            # <----  !!!        
            
            self.dictLbls[iP] = lab                                  # 
        else:
            lab = _lbl
            # print(f'lab для - {iP} -=============== уже есть')
# +++ * ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            
        if response == 1:
            if iP:                                                   #  
                lab.background = QColor("#fa7f72")
            else:
                lab.background = QColor("#ffaa00")
        else:
            lab.background = QColor("#54e346")
            
        lab.show()                                                  
        #print(f'response={response} -  iP={iP}')  

    def onClickLabel(self, objName, text):
        print(f'Вы кликнули: objName={objName}, text={text}')

# Заполнение таблицы пинга
    def tab_1(self):
        # Подключение к БД
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        
#        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip, Yi FROM ips"""
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip, Yi, x, y FROM ips"""             # <----
        
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()
        
        self.dictMove = { ip: (x, y) for ip, yi, x, y in records}            # <----


        # Перебор ip адресов
        for row, value in enumerate(records):
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value[0]))
            item_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value[1]))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, item)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item_2)
            self.row_count += 1

    # Отчиска плейн текст
    def clear_plainText(self):
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.clear()
        
        [lbl.hide() for lbl in self.dictLbls.values()]               # 
        self.dictLbls = {}                                           # 
       
# Старт\стоп пинга
    def startThread(self):
        dictIP = {}
        
        [lbl.hide() for lbl in self.dictLbls.values()]               # 
        self.dictLbls = {}                                           # 
        
        for row in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
            item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 1)
            if not item.checkState():
                item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("white"))
                item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("white"))
            dictIP[item.text()] = (row, 0, item.checkState())
            

        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = WorkThread(dictIP)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.coordinate)
            self.thread.start()
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Stop thread")

            style_stop = """QPushButton {
                         background-color: #fa7f72;
                         }
                         QPushButton:hover {
                         background-color: white;
                         }
                         QPushButton:pressed {
                         color: #626AB0;
                         background-color: #D5D4D4;
                         }"""

            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet(style_stop)
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.thread = None
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Start thread")

            style_start = """QPushButton {
                         background-color: #54e346;
                         }
                         QPushButton:hover {
                         background-color: white;
                         }
                         QPushButton:pressed {
                         color: #626AB0;
                         background-color: #D5D4D4;
                         }"""

            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet(style_start)

    # Отвечает за 1 пинг
    def on_threadSignal(self, response, k, v):
        # print(response, k, v)
        item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v[0], v[1])
        item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v[0], v[1]+1)
        #item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if response == 1:
            thread_1 = WorkThread_1(k, v)
            self.thread_1_list.append(thread_1)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].threadSignal_1.connect(self.on_threadSignal_1)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].threadSignal_1.connect(self.coordinate)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].start()
            self.thread_1_num += 1
        else:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#54e346"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#54e346"))

    # Отвечает за 2 пинг
    def on_threadSignal_1(self, response_1, k_1, v_1):
        #print(response_1, k_1, v_1)
        item_1 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v_1[0], v_1[1])
        item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v_1[0], v_1[1]+1)
        #item_1.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if response_1:
            item_1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#fa7f72"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#fa7f72"))

            sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip = '{}'""".format(k_1)
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in records:
                self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(f'{row[4]} | {row[1]} | {row[2]}\n{row[3]}\n')
        else:
            item_1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#ffaa00"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#ffaa00"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Енто шедееевр ! )

Answer (score 2):

я посмотрел только метод `coordinate()`:

- вы постоянно дергаете БД и это не правильно;
- ваши `labels` будут отражаться по ходу дела, добавьте  **`lab.show()`**, чтобы показать их;
- вы увидите сразу **ТРИ** `lab`, потому что они в цикле `for` и `records` в вашем примере три записи.
  И это будет после каждого получения результат пинга, потому что вы так написали.

---

```
import random                                                       # +++

...

    # Отвечает за лейблы
    def coordinate(self, response, response_1): # response, response_1 - результат пинга, прошел или нет
        # Подключение к БД
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT x, y, w, h FROM coords"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        # x, y - место | w, h - размер
        for x, y, w, h in records:
            lab = Label(parent=self.ui.tab)
# для тестирования                        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            lab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x+random.randint(10, 200), y+random.randint(10, 200), w, h))
            lab.setObjectName("")
            lab.setText("")
            lab.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel)
            if response == 1:
                if response_1:
                    lab.background = QColor("#fa7f72")
                else:
                    lab.background = QColor("#ffaa00")
            else:
                lab.background = QColor("#54e346")
                
            lab.show()                                                   # +++  <----
            
        #print(f'{response} - {records}')

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм.. а как мне тогда их показывать по отдельности а не все сразу ?

Comment: @OverNiko я так понимаю, что мой ответ вам уже полезен ? и зачем вам цикл `for` ?

Comment: Циклом я думал вытащить все labels на свои места

Comment: @OverNiko я не понимаю как вы собирались вытащить все labels. Уточните у вас должен меняться цвет лабел в зависимости от полученноно ответ - так ? И  второе уточнение - вы собираетесь перемещать лабелы, меняя коордираты или нет (они привязаны к определенному месту)  ?

Comment: Первое - да
Второе - Они привязаны к определённому месту и меняться их положение не будет, разве что, они будут удаляться или добавляться

Answer (score 1):

> OverNiko уточните у вас должен меняться цвет лабел в зависимости от полученноно ответ - так? 
> И второе уточнение - вы собираетесь перемещать лабелы, меняя коордираты или нет (они привязаны к определенному месту) ?

---

> Первое - да 
> Второе - Они привязаны к определённому месту и меняться их положение не будет, разве что, они будут удаляться или добавляться

---

---

Создаем словарь `self.dictLbls = {}` и туда записываем лабелы,
которые привязываем соответствующему `ip`.

```
import sys
import os
import random                                                       # +++
import sqlite3
import subprocess
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(818, 469)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/ico/Python.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:#b2b2b2;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 691, 383))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(im.png);")            # ! im.png
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setToolTip("")
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 5, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #FFAA00;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(75, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(291, 0))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1369, 16777215))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b2b2b2;")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 1, 4, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(54, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(153, 243, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 4, 2, 1, 2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem4, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(161, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(69, 31))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(133, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(285, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem5, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 297, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem6, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 818, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Лог панель"))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Изменение ip и данных"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Настройка ip"))
        self.pushButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Пинг старт/стоп"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Yi"))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Отчистить поле лог панели"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить таблицу"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Updae"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг ip"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip аддреса"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Порты"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключиться"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
#import res_rc


#------------------------ 1 пинг
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str, tuple)

    def __init__(self, dictIP):
        super().__init__()
        self.dictIP = dictIP
        # print(f'dictIP = {self.dictIP}')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for k, v in self.dictIP.items():
                if v[2] == 0:
                    response = subprocess.run(
                        ["ping", k, "-n", "1", "-w", "100"], 
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                    )
                    response = response.returncode
                    self.msleep(1)
                    self.threadSignal.emit(response, k, v)

#-------------------------- 2 пинг
class WorkThread_1(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal_1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str, tuple)

    def __init__(self, k, v):
        super().__init__()
        self.k_1 = k
        self.v_1 = v

    def run(self):
        response_1 = subprocess.run(
            ["ping", self.k_1, "-n", "4", "-w", "100"], 
            shell=True, 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        response_1 = response_1.returncode
        self.msleep(1)
        self.threadSignal_1.emit(response_1, self.k_1, self.v_1)


class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
    
    def __init__(
        self, 
        background=QColor("white"),
        parent=None
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._background = background
        self._change_stylesheet()
        
        self.setFixedSize(10, 10)                                    # +++  *

    @property
    def background(self):
        return self._background

    @background.setter
    def background(self, color):
        if self._background == color:
            return
        self._background = color
        self._change_stylesheet()

    def _change_stylesheet(self):
        qss = "QLabel {background-color:%s}" % (
            self.background.name(),
        )
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
#        self.clicked.emit(self.objectName(), self.text())
        self.clicked.emit(str(self.pos()), self.background.name())        # +++  * 


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startThread)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clear_plainText)

        self.thread = None

        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.table_index = 0
        self.row_count = 1
        self.count = 0

        self.tab_1()

        self.thread_1_list = []
        self.thread_1_num = 0
# +++  *
        self.dictLbls = {}                                           # +++  * !!!!!!!!!

# coordinate
    # Отвечает за лейблы
    # response - результат пинга, прошел или нет
    # iP - iP  
#    def coordinate(self, response, response_1): 
    def coordinate(self, response, iP):                             # +++  *

        '''  
        # Подключение к БД
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT x, y, w, h FROM coords"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()
        '''
# +++ * vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        _lbl = self.dictLbls.get(iP)                                # +++  *
        if not _lbl:                                                # +++  *
            # вам надо где-то в БД соответствующему iP имет pos для label !!!
            # для тестирования формирую рандомно
            x = random.randint(20, 650)                             # +++  * 
            y = random.randint(20, 350)                             # +++  *

            lab = Label(parent=self.ui.tab)
#            lab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x+random.randint(10, 200), y+random.randint(10, 200), w, h))
            lab.setObjectName("")
            lab.setText("")
            lab.clicked.connect(self.onClickLabel)
            lab.move(x, y)                                           # +++  * x, y
            
            self.dictLbls[iP] = lab                                  # +++  * !!!!!!!!!
        else:
            lab = _lbl
            # print(f'lab для - {iP} -=============== уже есть')
# +++ * ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            
        if response == 1:
            if iP:                                                   #  - response_1:
                lab.background = QColor("#fa7f72")
            else:
                lab.background = QColor("#ffaa00")
        else:
            lab.background = QColor("#54e346")
            
        lab.show()                                                  
        #print(f'response={response} -  iP={iP}')  

    def onClickLabel(self, objName, text):
        print(f'Вы кликнули: objName={objName}, text={text}')

    # Заполнение таблицы пинга
    def tab_1(self):
        # Подключение к БД
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip, Yi FROM ips"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        # Перебор ip адресов
        for row, value in enumerate(records):
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value[0]))
            item_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value[1]))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, item)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item_2)
            self.row_count += 1

    # Отчиска плейн текст
    def clear_plainText(self):
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.clear()
        
        [lbl.hide() for lbl in self.dictLbls.values()]               # +++  *
        self.dictLbls = {}                                           # +++  *
       
    # Старт\стоп пинга
    def startThread(self):
        dictIP = {}
        
        [lbl.hide() for lbl in self.dictLbls.values()]               # +++  *
        self.dictLbls = {}                                           # +++  *
        
        for row in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
            item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, 1)
            if not item.checkState():
                item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("white"))
                item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("white"))
            dictIP[item.text()] = (row, 0, item.checkState())

        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = WorkThread(dictIP)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.coordinate)
            self.thread.start()
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Stop thread")

            style_stop = """QPushButton {
                         background-color: #fa7f72;
                         }
                         QPushButton:hover {
                         background-color: white;
                         }
                         QPushButton:pressed {
                         color: #626AB0;
                         background-color: #D5D4D4;
                         }"""

            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet(style_stop)
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.thread = None
            self.ui.pushButton.setText("Start thread")

            style_start = """QPushButton {
                         background-color: #54e346;
                         }
                         QPushButton:hover {
                         background-color: white;
                         }
                         QPushButton:pressed {
                         color: #626AB0;
                         background-color: #D5D4D4;
                         }"""

            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet(style_start)

    # Отвечает за 1 пинг
    def on_threadSignal(self, response, k, v):
        # print(response, k, v)
        item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v[0], v[1])
        item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v[0], v[1]+1)
        #item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if response == 1:
            thread_1 = WorkThread_1(k, v)
            self.thread_1_list.append(thread_1)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].threadSignal_1.connect(self.on_threadSignal_1)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].threadSignal_1.connect(self.coordinate)
            self.thread_1_list[self.thread_1_num].start()
            self.thread_1_num += 1
        else:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#54e346"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#54e346"))

    # Отвечает за 2 пинг
    def on_threadSignal_1(self, response_1, k_1, v_1):
        #print(response_1, k_1, v_1)
        item_1 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v_1[0], v_1[1])
        item_2 = self.ui.tableWidget.item(v_1[0], v_1[1]+1)
        #item_1.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if response_1:
            item_1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#fa7f72"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#fa7f72"))

            sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ip = '{}'""".format(k_1)
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in records:
                self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(f'{row[4]} | {row[1]} | {row[2]}\n{row[3]}\n')
        else:
            item_1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#ffaa00"))
            item_2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#ffaa00"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "вам надо где-то в БД соответствующему iP имет pos для label !!!" - не понял

Comment: @OverNiko я в примере место расположения для лабел формирую рандомно, а вы по каким координатам собираетесь их располагать ?   Я ответил на ваш вопрос: "Изменять цвет лейблу по мере пингования " ?

Comment: Все координаты у меня находятся в бд. Оранжевый цвет не выдаёт (использую рандомные координаты) и цвета лейблов не успевают за цветами пинга

Comment: @OverNiko о координатах - если вы имеете ввиду таблицу `coords` , то она подойдет, если в колонку `id` прописать значения ip-адресов или в таблицу `ips` добавьте две колонки `x` и `y`

Comment: Закинул координаты в ips

Comment: Куда мне цикл вытаскивания координат вставить ?

Comment: iP оно как бы есть, но его как бы и нет... откуда берётся ?

Comment: @OverNiko я добавил ответ с вариантом как это можно сделать.